# QSettings how to read ini without value of keys

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I have config:

```
[Users]
joe
bill
dona
serg
```

I need `QStringList` with all usernames.

```
QSettings ini("/tmp/users.ini", QSettings::NativeFormat);
ini.beginGroup("Users");
QStringList keys = ini.allKeys();
qDebug() << keys;
ini.endGroup();
```

This not work :(

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Show your output.

Comment: Where such ini file comes from? Qt docs say: "Each setting consists of a QString that specifies the setting's name (the key) and a QVariant that stores the data associated with the key.". I think `QSettings` does not support such format.

Answer (score 0):

I change the config to

```
[Users]
joe=1
bill=1
dona=1
serg=1
```

And it work now.

Comment: in the future you should be able to verify format issues with `QSettings::status()`